# Why do I get System Exception thrown only with Excel 2007?

Tags: c#, excel, exception, excel-interop

I have a List that holds some objects, which properties I want to write in a en Excel. The code works perfectly with Excel 2013. The issue comes when I try to run it in a computer that only has Excel 2007.

I already looked in different links and discussions but none of them seem to have the solution to this issue. I already changes the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference to the one located in the correct path and different methods.

I get this error:

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

In computers with newer versions of Excel, the code runs perfectly and I get the output I wish, but with 2007 Excel I get the previously mentioned exception.

Any solutions or ideas?

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` there are different references (libraries) you should use depending on the version of Excel you are targeting; `Library not registered` reason why you are seeing this error.

Comment: EPPlus isn't an answer to your question, but I recommend considering it anyway. Just as a free public service I would recommend to almost anyone using or considering interop to use an OpenXML library instead. Interop was around before Excel documents used OpenXML, so it always appears as a way to create or read Excel. But it has many drawbacks, one of which is that the computer must have Excel installed and even then you have to worry about which version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) as it does not require interop.

Comment: Providing a link only answer is not suggested here. Links can become dead and irrelevant to the questions itself. Please update your post of how your answer provides a solution to the OP problem.